# Consume the firebase error with router action function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, react-router

I wanted Cosnume the Firebase Authentication Errors but because it is at the top level i cannot use Usestate i want to a find a solution to somehow render the error into the JSX.

i cannot move the action function inside react compoent and also i cannot use the usestate at the top level, i tried arrays push method and also starting the variable as an emplty string then i assigned the error value to it, but everytime it returns empty array or string:

```
export async function LoginAction({request}) {

  let formData = await request.formData();
const email = formData.get('email');
const password = formData.get('password');
const confirmPassword = formData.get('confirmPassword');

// console.log(password, confirmPassword);
if (password !== confirmPassword) {
  // console.log('password does not match');
} else {
  try {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    // console.log(userCredential.user);
    return userCredential;
    
  } catch (error) {
// I WANT TO CONSUME THIS ERROR MESSAGE AND RENDER IN THE JSX.
  }
}

return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `errorElement` for the route rendering the `Login` component that can read the current route error, and simply throw an error from the route action.

Example:

```
import { useRouteError } from 'react-router-dom';

const LoginErrorElement = () => {
  const error = useRouteError();

  return (
    ... render error message to JSX ...
  );
};
```

```js
async function loginAction({ request }) {
  let formData = await request.formData();
  const email = formData.get("email");
  const password = formData.get("password");
  const confirmPassword = formData.get("confirmPassword");

  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    // console.log('password does not match');
  } else {
    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      return userCredential;
    } catch (error) {
      // handle the error locally, e.g. analytics logging, etc...
      throw error; // <-- re-throw the error
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
    action: loginAction,
    errorElement: <LoginErrorElement />
  },
  ...
]);
```

### Demo

[image: Edit consume-the-firebase-error-with-router-action-function]

If you would like the action to return an error back to the `Login` component then move the `useRouteError` hook/logic into `Login` and provide `Login` also as the `errorElement`.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
    action: loginAction,
    errorElement: <Login />
  }
  ...
]);
```

```
const Login = () => {
  const error = useRouteError();

  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <label>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Confirm password: <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>

      {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
    </Form>
  );
};
```

### Demo

[image: Edit consume-the-firebase-error-with-router-action-function (forked)]